# How to do nested group by in RavenDB multi map index

Tags: c#, linq, mapreduce, ravendb

I have two different document collections in my RavenDB database - Teams and Matches. The documents look like this:

```
public class Team {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int LeaguePosition { get; set; }
}

public class Match {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string HomeTeamName { get; set; }
    public string AwayTeamName { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
}
```

So basically I have teams and matches between these teams. However, for certain operations I need to get an entity which look something like the following from the database:

```
public class MatchWithExtraData {
    public string Id { get; set; } // Id from the match document.
    public string HomeTeamId { get; set; }
    public string HomeTeamName { get; set; }
    public int HomeTeamPosition { get; set; }
    public string AwayTeamId { get; set; }
    public string AwayTeamName { get; set; }
    public int AwayTeamPosition { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartTime { get; set; }
}
```

What I want is really the match document but with extra fields for the home and away teams' ids and league positions. Basically join the match document on home and away team name with two team documents, one for the home team and one for the away team. I figured that a multi map/reduce index should do the trick so I have started with the following index:

```
public class MatchWithExtraDataIndex: AbstractMultiMapIndexCreationTask<MatchWithExtraData> {
    public MatchWithExtraData() {
        AddMap<Team>(
            teams => from team in teams
                     select new {
                         Id = (string)null,
                         HomeTeamId = team.Id,
                         HomeTeamName = team.Name,
                         HomeTeamPosition = team.LeaguePosition,
                         AwayTeamId = team.Id,
                         AwayTeamName = team.Name,
                         AwayTeamPosition = team.LeaguePosition,
                         StartTime = (DateTime?)null
                     }
        );
        AddMap<Match>(
            matches => from match in matches
                       select new {
                           Id = match.Id,
                           HomeTeamId = (string)null,
                           HomeTeamName = match.HomeTeamName,
                           HomeTeamPosition = 0,
                           AwayTeamId = (string)null,
                           AwayTeamName = match.AwayTeamName,
                           AwayTeamPosition = 0,
                           StartTime = match.StartTime
                       }
        );
        Reduce = results => from result in results
                            // NOW WHAT?
    }
}
```

The reduce part is the one I can't figure out since there are two teams in each match. I think I need to do a nested group by, first on the HomeTeamName, and then on the AwayTeamName but I can't figure out how to do that.

Maybe this is more a LINQ problem than a RavenDB problem. But how would such a nested group by statement look? Or could it be done in another way?

Answer (score 0):

You are better off using Transform Results for that, or includes.
See the docs here: http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/querying/handling-document-relationships

Comment: I'm not sure how to use either tranform results or includes in this case since what I've got is the team _name_, not the team _id_. And as far as I can tell, I need the id to use includes or live reflection in transforms. Am I right or am I overlooking something?